# Как получить callback на том же потоке где был запрос (Retrofit)?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

Проблема в том, что не важно на в каком потоке был сделан запрос, колбек будет возвращен на main потоке. Можно сделать так, чтоб колбеки прилетали в бекграунд, но для этого нужно изменить конфигурацию как описано в этом ответе: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41370867/5709159

```
...
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(/* your url */)
        .callbackExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())  <--- THIS LINE
        // other builder options...
        .build();
...
```

но тогда все колбеки будут прилетать в бекграунд, а мне нужно, чтоб я мог контролировать какие колбеки прилетают в бекграунд, а какие в main и для этого было бы очень удобно получать колбек на том же потоке на котором был сделан запрос, но такой опции я не вижу.

Вопрос, как сделать так, чтоб можно было определять перед запросом на каком потоке получить колбек? Не хочется иметь две конфигурации Retrofit (как описано выше) одну с указанием на бекграунд, а вторую дефолтную.

Comment: Напишите либо свой "умный" Executor, либо что-то типа CallbackRouter и все колбэки прогоняйте через него. Мне больше первый вариант импонирует, там все дело в имплементации одного метода.

Comment: Можно использовать RxJava (методы будут возвращать Observable) или корутины (suspend методы), там элементарное переключение потоков где угодно

Comment: Можно запускаться в бэкграунде синхронно `backgroundExecutor.execute(()->{Response<ResultDTO> result = service.getTasks().execute();});` а для мэйна асинхронно с колбэком через enqueue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда нужно получить ответ в главном (или заданном в конфигурации) потоке используйте асинхронный запрос с колбеком

```java
call.enqueue(callback);
```

Когда нужно получить ответ в вызывающем потоке используйте синхронный (блокирующий) запрос

```java
try {
    Response<T> response = call.execute();
    // onResponse equivalent
    ...
} catch (Throwable t) {
    // onFailure equivalent
    ...
}
```